# Nested map structure

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have a map defined like this:

```
Map<Long, Long> foo = new TreeMap<Long, Long>();
```

For each entry into the map, I also want to map those entries to a `Boolean`. How can I do this? This is what I tried so far but it doesn't look right. What I want to achieve is that for every entry in `mask`, there should be a corresponding `Boolean` value that it is assigned to.

```
Map<Long, Boolean> mask = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
SortedMap<Long, Map<Long, Boolean>> pairs =  new TreeMap<Long, Map<Long, Boolean>>();

mask.put(new Long(2), Boolean.FALSE);
mask.put(new Long(3), Boolean.FALSE);
mask.put(new Long(3), Boolean.FALSE);

pairs.put(new Long(1), new Long(2));
pairs.put(new Long(1), new Long(3));
pairs.put(new Long(2), new Long(3));
```

The constraint is that I can only use the built-in types. I had a solution before which had a custom object which allowed me to easily achieve this but due to the project design, I cannot create new types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that encapsulates both values and make a map of that:

```
class Pair {
    public final boolean booleanValue;
    public final long longValue;

    public Pair(boolean booleanValue, long longValue) {
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }
}

Map<Long,Pair> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(1L, new Pair(false, 123));
map.put(2L, new Pair(true,  456));
map.put(3L, new Pair(false, 789));
```

Or use two maps having the same keys:

```
Map<Long,Boolean> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Long,Long>    map2 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put(1L, false); map2.put(1L, 123L);
map1.put(2L,  true); map2.put(2L, 456L);
map1.put(3L, false); map2.put(3L, 789L);
```

Comment: The constraint is that I can only use the built-in types. I had a solution before which had a custom object which allowed me to easily achieve this but due to the project design, I cannot create new types.

Comment: Yes, I will use the two maps.

Comment: @I.K. I'm curious what sort of project design causes that constraint?

Comment: let's just say that I am working at a company where you could make a classic Dilbert cartoon every day. They are doing everything wrong from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to map both a Long and a Boolean to the same key entry?

If that's the case, and you can't create your own custom objects, you just need to have two maps:

```
Map<Long, Long> pairs = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
Map<Long, Boolean> mask = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
```

Then just use the same key entry for both:

```
pairs.put(1L, 5L);
mask.put(1L, false);

pairs.put(2L, 20L);
mask.put(2L, true);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object that has a Long and Boolean and that object put into the map.

Comment: The constraint is that I can only use the built-in types. I had a solution before which had a custom object which allowed me to easily achieve this but due to the project design, I cannot create new types.

Comment: Then try Guava Multimap and insert objects. But this is not a built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

What about a holder ?

```
private class MyHolder
{
    public Boolean boolValue;
    public Long longValue;
}

Map<Long, MyHolder> myMap = new HashMap<Long, MyHolder>();

MyHolder h = new MyHolder();
h.boolValue = true;
h.longValue = 1L;
myMap.put(1L, h);
```